# How can I split a list into smaller lists in Camel?

Tags: apache-camel

I have flow where I read from a file, convert to CSV, and then convert each line to objects. So I end up with a List. Now I want to split this into smaller lists, and process each in parallel. I can use split() to get individual entries, but all my attempts at using aggregate has not resulted in a list, just single items.

```
from("file://")
  .unmarshal(csvDataFormat)
  .to("bean:personReader")
  .split(body())
  .aggregate( ??? )
  .to("bean:send")
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the composed message processor eip pattern: http://camel.apache.org/composed-message-processor.html where you can do a fork/join processing?

If so take a look at that link above, and see the examples with *splitter only* as the splitter eip in Camel has built in aggregation, so you can join all the splitted messages together to a single message again.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a custom aggregate strategy, seeing as the AbstractListAggregationStrategy didn't quite fit either:

```
class ListAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {
    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(final Exchange oldExchange, final Exchange newExchange) {
        final Object value = newExchange.getIn().getBody();
        if (oldExchange == null) {
            newExchange.getIn().setBody(Lists.newArrayList(value));
            return newExchange;
        } else {
            oldExchange.getIn().getBody(List.class).add(value);
            return oldExchange;
        }
    }
}
```

Then: 
    from("direct:source")
    .aggregate()
      .constant(true)
      .completionSize(1000)
      .aggregationStrategy(new ListAggregationStrategy())
      .to("direct:target");